# Chrome Extension Got Disabled By Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-contacts-api

I have pushed a minor fix to my chrome extension. After that the button disappears and extension in extensions list (chrome://extensions/) contains text "This extension may have been corrupted". After click to "repair" button the extension repairs, but after second click it disappears again.

I made a minor change to "permissions"

This is the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cashpit-cashback-for-amaz/fhahonhpebjnfdpcocgecimkanggfehi

If extension was loaded from source (load unpacked), it works good.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. There was one several years ago which was fixed so this is probably different. Things to try: 1) Chrome Canary, 2) a new browser profile of the main browser, 3) disable antivirus temporarily and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried all this, no success at all. When you install the extension, is it the same for you?

Comment: It gets disabled in Chrome 80 and Canary but not in Chrome 78 so it's probably a bug.

Comment: Anything I can do about it? Maybe upload the version before the bug?

Comment: Since it's unclear what triggers the bug, go ahead and try various things.